# Installing tipfy using pip in a virtualenv

Tags: macos, google-app-engine, virtualenv, tipfy

I installed the [Google App Engine SDK for Python](http://code.google.com/appengine/downloads.html#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python) on OS X using the `GoogleAppEngineLauncher-1.4.1.dmg` package.

I created a Python 2.5 based [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.openplans.org/) and then installed [werkzeug](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/) and [tipfy](http://www.tipfy.org/) as follows:

```
mkvirtualenv -p python2.5 tipfy-sandbox
pip install werkzeug
pip install tipfy
```

However, when I run the Python interpreter and `import tipfy` and then introspect [tipfy](http://www.tipfy.org/) with `dir(tipfy)`, all I receive is:

```
['__doc__', '__name__', '__path__', 'ext']
```

Surely that's not everything from a fully installed [tipfy](http://www.tipfy.org/).

1. Is it possible to install [tipfy](http://www.tipfy.org/) using [pip](http://pip.openplans.org/)?
2. What else do I need to install to get [tipfy](http://www.tipfy.org/) working in a [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.openplans.org/)?
3. When installing [tipfy](http://www.tipfy.org/) using [pip](http://pip.openplans.org/), can I still use the [GoogleAppEngineLauncher](http://code.google.com/appengine/downloads.html#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python)? Do I have to use the [GoogleAppEngineLauncher](http://code.google.com/appengine/downloads.html#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_Python)?

### Configuration

- I'm using the OS X installed Python 2.5.4
- [virtualenv](http://virtualenv.openplans.org/) 1.5.1
- [pip](http://pip.openplans.org/) 0.8.1

Comment: Did you ever solve this? Try checking `tipfy.__path__`.

Comment: No, I haven't solved this yet.

Comment: have you tried to [install tipfy](http://www.tipfy.org/wiki/guide/installation/#do-it-yourself-installation) after you actived your virtualenv?

Comment: @Daniel Ozean: Yes, when I try to install tipfy via `pip install tipfy` my virtualenv is active.

Comment: try to install tipfy by following the ["Do-it-yourself installation"](http://goo.gl/x4Xh5) in your virtualenv

Answer (score 1):

The recomendend way to use tipfy is via buildout, with the recipe provided in

http://www.tipfy.org/wiki/guide/installation/

you can try to use virtualenv and run the buildout inside this one (i use this one and works, but without sense, buildout 1.5.x give the same isolation level than buildout now)